# xarray where on netcdf big data

Tags: python, bigdata, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a temperature variable with dims [time,plev,lat,lon]. I'm using a crude method to select the troposphere by masking out temperatures that increase along plev.
Right now I'm using a very inefficient code:

```
ifile = xr.open_dataset('example.nc')

#temperature variable
ta = ifile.ta

for lat in range(144):
    for lon in range (90):
        for time in range(480):
             for plev in range(1,19,1):
                  if ta[time,plev-1,lat,lon]<ta[time,plev,lat,lon]:
                        ta[time,plev:,lat,lon] = np.nan
```

As you might have figured out, this takes forever to run. I used to use xarray.where for simple masking, but I can't seem to figure it out for a 4-D array with this particular conditional.
Does anyone know of an efficient alternative, maybe with Dask or if I can use xarray.where in some way?

Comment: Can you use `ta.where(lambda x: x.diff("plev") > 0)`?

Comment: Thanks! This helps. My condition is plev>0 for xarray.diff. The default, label = "upper" gets rid of the surface pressure, so I'm using label = "lower" to retain the lower pressure level.